# c++ String encoding for special characters

Tags: c++, unicode, utf

I'm creating my own font rendering system and am using a bitmap font.

Each font has its own xml file which include integers that represent `ALT+???`
So if I create a string `l("abc");` it would show up as `97 98 99`.

I get that integer code with this code:

```
int c = (unsigned char) text[i];
SubTexture* t = font.getLetter(to_wstring(c).c_str());
```

This is all going fine, until I use the special `ALT+???` codes for example:

```
l("♂♀♪♫☼");
```

It doesn't give me `11 12 13 14 15` but it returns something else, depending on the encoding used in the file. I tried using all the different encoding formats but non returned the integers I was looking for. I was hoping someone could help me with this problem. Maybe there is a better way then converting it to an `unsigned char`?

Edit: Maybe I should note that I use Visual Studio 2012 and setting 'general->Character Set' is set to: 'Use Unicode Character Set'

Comment: You appear to be expecting [Windows Code Page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), which you would get if you were using a command window to create the code. It sounds like you're using some editor though, which one?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, I tried using windows code page 437, but Visual studio 2012 could not save the file using that code page

Comment: I don't know if there's another code page that supports those odd characters. If you use wide characters like `L"♂♀♪♫☼"` then you'd get UTF-16, but the character codes no longer fit in a `char`.

Comment: `int c = (unsigned char) text[i];` ... what?

Comment: @MarkRansom If I use that, it shows up as: `â™`

Comment: Not `unsigned char` but `wchar_t`. And once you've done that you need to change `to_wstring` too, but it should now be incredibly simple.

Comment: @MarkRansom int c= (wchar_t) text[i]; returns 9794 9792

Comment: Yes, that looks correct: [U+2642](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2642/index.htm) [U+2640](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2640/index.htm).

Comment: @MarkRansom But there is no way to make it 11? Because I would have to edit a damn load of stuff it thats not possible in some way.. :(

Comment: You can use a hex literal instead: `"\x0b\x0c"`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, that will do for now :D

Comment: Or, you could just go back to a command window to create the code.